# determine what started android app

Tags: android

How can I tell what started an Android app?  Specifically I'd like to be able to determine if the app was started by Android Studio - either in normal or debug mode - and then display some additional menu options.

Thanks.

Comment: can you elaborate

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer

Add a custom extra to your Run configuration on Android Studio, and check for its presence in your intent's extras.

---

### Detailed explanation

Android Studio is, by default, starting the application exactly like any launcher would do:

```
adb shell am start -n "fr.enoent.customextrasample/fr.enoent.customextrasample.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

But you have a way to pass in extra values. First, let's add logs in our activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        for (String category : getIntent().getCategories()) {
            Log.d("Category", category);
        }

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
                Log.d("Extra", key + ": " + extras.get(key));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When running through Android Studio:

```
D/Category: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

When running from the launcher:

```
D/Category: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
D/Extra: profile: 0
```

There's maybe something to do with the `profile` extra, but I wouldn't rely on it. It's probably related to the multi-users feature of Android, and will probably not be there every time.

But you *can* change the way Android Studio launches your application.

Open your Run configuration dialog:
[image: How to open Run configuration dialog]

Then edit the launch flags, to add a custom extra. The syntax is `-e CustomExtraName CustomExtraValue`. Here, I added `-e ANDROID_STUDIO true`.
[image: Edited run configuration]
You could probably achieve the same thing with a custom category. The syntax would then be `-c YourCustomCategory`. You can mix and match custom categories, multiple extras… A detailed `am` documentation is available [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#am).

Back to our application. Let's run it again, via Android Studio:

```
D/Category: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
D/Extra: ANDROID_STUDIO: true
```

And from the launcher:

```
D/Category: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
D/Extra: profile: 0
```

Hooray!

You now have an easy way to check if your application has been started from Android Studio or from something else:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    if (extras.containsKey("ANDROID_STUDIO")) {
        Log.d("Start", "Ran from Android Studio");
    } else {
        Log.d("Start", "Ran from something else");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is perfect and provides a really nice way to determine whether the debugger is running.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio, you can use

`BuildConfig.DEBUG` to determine that your app is debug or release!

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
  Log.d(TAG, "debug")
}
else{
  Log.d(TAG, "release")
}
```

**Note:** Make sure you choose right Build Variant from Build Variants!

Comment: From the question: *either in normal or debug mode*. Also note that `BuildConfig.DEBUG` is generated by Gradle and not by Android Studio.

Comment: @MarcPlano-Lesay ok then you should dare to answer, and get well soon my son!

Comment: Here you go. Sorry it took so long, I was writing an actual answer, not a remotely related one-liner just here to earn some reputation.